# Shortest Route to Multiple Destinations, Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Im Looking for a way to generate the shortest way to multiple destinations through windows mobile 8. I have the capability to provide the lat and long to the locations i want, need a way to get the route to map control on windows mobile. I need to get the shortest distance to the closets destination and it goes on like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use google's distance matrix API to find the the shortest distance

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start#sample-request

Then to find the route you can use google's direction API

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start#sample-request